# Undefined navigator.push React-native 0.43.4

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using the Navigator component of react-native but i still get error when i want to push to anthor page `push undefined is not a function` so there is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    StyleSheet,
    Navigator,
    Text,
    TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';
import Home from './Home';
import Main from './Main';

class MainApp extends Component {


    _navigate(){
        this.props.navigator.push({
            name: Home
        })
    }


    render() {


        return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => this._navigate() }>
                <Text>GO To View</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>

        </View>


        );
    }
}
```

and Home component

```
class Home extends Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Welcome Hello</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },

});

export default Home;
```

I still get this error, I am a beginner in react-native so help me please ? why react-native so hard ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ! First of all, RN is not so hard ^^ I started two weeks ago don't worry it will become easier !

I'll give you an example if you're ok with that !

**MainApp**

```
renderScene(route,nav) {
switch (route.screen) {
  case "LaunchScreen":
    return <LaunchScreen navigator={nav} />
  case "LoginScreen":
    return <LoginScreen navigator={nav} />
  case "ListBillScreen":
    return <ListBillScreen navigator={nav} />
  case "AddBillScreen":
    return <AddBillScreen navigator={nav} />
  case "BillScreen":
    return <BillScreen navigator={nav} bill={route.props}/>
  case "PersistanceDemo":
    return <PersistanceDemo navigator={nav} />
  }

}

render () {
 return (
   <Navigator
          initialRoute={{screen: 'LaunchScreen'}}
          renderScene={(route, nav) => {return this.renderScene(route, nav)}}
        />
      )
 }
}
```

You set all your "Routes" in the mainApp okay?

After that, if you want to navigate between views in others .js, you need to do this way :

```
this.props.navigator.push({ screen: 'AddBillScreen' });
```

You need to navigate with the name of your screen ! Once you've done that, it will be soooo easy for you to navigate between views you will see !

Keep strong !

Answer (score 1):

After some hours of work, i resolve my problem 
First i create MainApp and i define a Navigator with initialRoute my code look like this

```
class MainApp extends Component {
    renderScene(route, navigator) {
            console.log(route, navigator);
            if (route.component) {
                return React.createElement(route.component, { navigator });
            }
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <Navigator
                    initialRoute={{name: 'Home', component: Home}}
                    configureScene={() => {
                        return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;
                    }}
                    renderScene={this.renderScene}
                />
            );
        }
}
```

and after in Home screen i use this function

```
   _navigate() {
        this.props.navigator.replace({
            name: 'Main',
            component: Main
        });
    }
```

So now my project work well , the key is create a screen route hope it useful