# Cannot able to navigate to another screen in react native

Tags: react-native

I have made login authentication using POST API, I received success response, inside success response, I just want to navigate to other screen say for e.g(from Login screen to Videos screen).But it's not working for me pls look at my code and tell me where I made mistakes.

```
index.android.js:
     export default class Registration extends Component {
     render() {
     const { navigation } =this.props;
     return (
     <Login navigation={ navigation }/>);
     }
   }

src/Login.js:

class Login extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.redirect=this.redirect.bind(this)
    this.state = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        errors: '',
        }
    }
    On button submit i just calling below method
     CallSignIn() {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/users/login", { method: "POST", body: JSON.stringify({ email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password }), headers: { 'x-api-key': '7LH9ElCr4p1GLiMXAWLu0a9UsvKZ4wJr7t1N3ewh', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
            this.setState({ showProgress: false })
            this.redirect()
         Alert.alert("success:", JSON.stringify(responseData.token));
         })
        .done();
       }
 redirect() {
const { navigate } = props.navigation;
    navigate('Videos')
}
}
```

Comment: look at this, it can help you , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43682601/undefined-navigator-push-react-native-0-43-4/43739206#43739206

Comment: thanks i am using latest version of react its now deprecated.

Comment: Show your StackNavigator code.

Comment: Login is my stack navigator

Comment: Does it shows the alert dialog. If not, you should put `.catch((e)=>{console.log(e)})` just before the `.done()`